# Finite order arithmetic and ETCS

Tags: lo.logic, ct.category-theory, set-theory, reference-request

I'm looking for a reference to the statement that Lawvere's [Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets (ETCS)](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/11/tr11abs.html) is equal in proof-theoretic strength to finite order arithmetic.  The person who informed me of this said it was well-known in certain circles, but he couldn't think of a reference.

Actually, all I need is a reference to one half of the equivalence: that anything provable in finite order arithmetic is provable in ETCS.  The story: I've been looking at Colin McLarty's paper [A finite order arithemetic foundation for cohomology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1773), which shows that nothing stronger than finite order arithmetic is needed anywhere in EGA or SGA.  I want to state that nothing stronger than ETCS is needed anywhere in EGA or SGA.  To back that up with references, I therefore need something that relates ETCS to finite order arithmetic.

---

**Edit** This question has generated lots of discussion about McLarty's paper.  I'm genuinely interested in that discussion, but I'd also like to emphasize that it's peripheral to my question, which is simply a reference request: where can I find it stated/proved that ETCS is equal in strength to finite order arithmetic?

---

**Further edit** Maybe I can make this question more transparent to experts in non-categorical set theory.  ETCS is well-known to have the same strength as the membership-based theory known as "bounded Zermelo with choice" or "restricted Zermelo with choice".  (One reference: Mac Lane and Moerdijk, *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*, Section VI.10.)  The axioms are extensionality, empty set, pairing, union, power set, foundation, restricted comprehension, infinity, and choice.  Here "restricted comprehension" means that we only consider formulas that are restricted in the sense that all quantifiers are of the form "$\forall x \in y$" or "$\exists x \in y$".

Comment: Ok, isn't $(\mathbb{N},0,s,+,\cdot,\lt,P\mathbb{N},\ldots,P^n\mathbb{N})$, where $+$,$\cdot$ and $\lt$ have their standard meanings in a topos, a model of $(n+1)^{st}$-order arithmetic?

Comment: Ah, the comprehension axiom - is that the issue?

Comment: David: I don't know.  I simply want a reference!

Comment: How about http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6357?

Comment: I think that ETCS should interpret the theories ETR[n*] for each natural number $n$, and ETR[n*] interprets $Z_{n+2}$, $(n+2)$-order arithmetic.

Comment: How do finite-order arithmetic and Zermelo set theory compare? Both seem strongly connected with $V_{\omega+\omega}$, which is iterating the power set on the hereditary finite sets $\omega$ many times.

Comment: The premise of this question is false. McLarty's paper only addresses part of the foundations of cohomology, ignoring that crystalline cohomology is another essential tool in arithmetic applications that is not addressed in EGA and SGA and entails more serious set-theoretic issues. So his claim that such-and-such suffices for all of "cohomological number theory" is not proved, and he never makes claims about what is needed "anywhere in EGA and SGA", as he cannot since he hasn't read those references in their entirety.  Have you? If not, your goal merits reconsideration.

Comment: @Joel, I presume you mean to get at the purported equiconsistency of ETCS and finite-order arithmetic via the relationship between ETCS and BZC?

Comment: @xuhan: I guess I'm not sure 26 letters suffice to write every word in English since I haven't read the entire OED...

Comment: Xuhan, can you tell me exactly what the "premise" in my question is that you believe to be false?  You mention tools "not addressed in EGA and SGA", which may well be important for all sorts of reasons, but that's not what I was asking about.  Also, I believe McLarty *does* make claims about what is needed for EGA and SGA: e.g. on p.1, he writes "This paper founds the EGA and SGA on axioms with the proof theoretic strength of finite order arithmetic".   

Comment: @Francois: Your OED statement doesn't make sense, since by definition English words are written with the English alphabet. As far as math goes, I am not claiming that one cannot prove theorems about the properties of proofs that one has not read.  But if you read McLarty's paper, you'll see that he limits the scope of his conclusions to far less generality that Tom Leinster is claiming.  So unless Tom has read EGA and SGA, his description of the scope of McLarty's conclusions is unjustified and so the formulation of his goal thereby merits reconsideration. That is all I am saying.

Comment: David: thanks for the reference, but which result in that paper are you looking at?  (I observe that ETR[0] includes replacement, which ETCS doesn't.)

Comment: Xuhan, I think we both know that I haven't read all of EGA and SGA. But can you explain to me the difference between what McLarty says on p.1 and how I described his paper in my question? I'd like to understand the distinction you're making. – Tom Leinster 0 secs ago

Comment: @Tom - ah, I'm not looking at a result in the paper when I say "I think that [something that turns out to be a bunch of nonsense]". As a riposte, let me ask if we have a reference that ETCS can interpret, say second-order arithmetic...

Comment: @Tom: McLarty's theorems in their precise form are limited to statements about specific cohomological aspects of SGA.  He never proves that such-and-such is "not needed anywhere" in EGA and SGA.  His motivation is the applications of cohomological methods in number theory, and if that is also your motivation then you should also be aware that McLarty does not address crystalline cohomology, which has tremendous arithmetic importance and yet presents more serious set-theoretic problems than fppf or etale. It would be *very* interesting if you can say something about the crystalline case!

Comment: Joel: I'm afraid I don't know - I was hoping someone like you might be able to tell me...

Comment: Xuhan: thanks for the clarification.  Actually, my primary interest here has nothing to do with EGA or SGA: I just wanted an example to indicate the scope of ETCS.  But I'd like to know: assuming McLarty has made no mistakes, would you say there is any overstatement in the following two sentences from p.1 of his paper?  (1) "We formalize the practical insight by founding the entire toolkit of EGA and SGA at the level of finite order arithmetic".  (2) "This paper founds the EGA and SGA on axioms with the proof theoretic strength of finite order arithmetic."

Comment: @Tom, why not write to McLarty and point him to this question? He's always responded to my emails. 

Comment: David, no, I was just curious about those two set theories, since I understand Zermelo theory fairly well, but have less intuition for finite-order arithmetic. In contrast, I have very little intuition for ETCS and frankly find it difficult to work in that theory.

Comment: Thanks, Colin. Nice to know my intuition wasn't completely off.

Comment: @Xuhan. The fact is that little of EGA or SGA raises any set theoretic issues. Much of it is commutative algebra transparently formalizable in second order arithmetic. While crystalline cohomology does go beyond that, it may not go beyond third order arithmetic, and clearly is far short of arithmetic of all finite orders. The stronger claims in "arxiv.org/abs/1102.1773" are supported by arguments in the paper.

Comment: As Tom knows, ETCS in the original published form is proof theoretically equivalent to Zermelo set theory with the separation axiom restricted to formulas with all quantifiers bounded. That proof is published in several places. Both those theories are equivalent to the arithmetic of all finite orders. The result does follow from the result I address in arxiv.org/abs/1207.6357 but that draft is defective and I have a repair in progress. I first said the fact about finite order arithmetic is simpler than that paper, but actually I do not know it is, and anyway I do not know a reference for it.

Comment: @xuhan: The reason why you know you only need 26 letters to read English is precisely the same reason why you may be able to propose an alternative system for EGA and SGA without reading the whole thing. EGA and SGA have a definite logical structure and only key parts are necessary to analyze to achieve this kind of goal.

Comment: @Tom: Statements about the scope of cohomological aspects are all McLarty addresses in his proofs. There are many non-cohomological aspects, and it is a real issue to rigorously address restating everything within McLarty's framework if one wants to make more general claims. Barring a review of the entire tomes, (1) and (2) are not justified. Also, the 2nd paragraphs of 3.4.1 and 3.5 are technically incorrect (e.g., quasi-compactness is not the only issue for sites beyond etale and fppf), raising doubt about the *precise* generality he achieves, and he doesn't handle the crystalline theory. 

Comment: @Joel David Hamkins.  The place to go for intuition on set theoretic issues in ETCS is A.R.D. Mathias, 1992: "What is Mac Lane missing", in W.J.H. Judah and H.Woodin (eds), `Set Theory of the Continuum', although that paper puts ETCS into a membership-based form.  The title is a joke as Adrien uses "MacLane" as the name of a set theory.   In short, you cannot use induction on the natural numbers in unbounded set theoretic constructions so you can prove each transfinite cardinal has a successor but not that there are unboundedly many of them.

Comment: Colin, I know that article, but I have always taken it primarily as criticism of Mac Lane's set theory, in that Mathias's main project seems to be to show how weak and limiting that set theory is.

Comment: @Francois: What is the "definite logical structure" of these works and precisely what are the "key parts" (and especially: how does one know they are the *only* parts one needs to look at)?  There are a lot of cohomological constructions out there! The very end of section 3 of McLarty's paper observes that matters need to be thought through in more detail, since restricting attention to countably generated modules over countable rings is an impractical restriction for pushing through many proofs (even if one can make modifications on a case-by-case basis).

Comment: @Xuhan The definite logical structure is the clear articulation of scheme theory, derived functors, toposes, and derived categories  Grothendieck created.  You find which parts you need to look at by working very hard to grasp the point each part -- certainly without working through each proof. But I would be interested to hear your more specific objections as i will be talking about this over the winter.  

Comment: @xuhan, see http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2012-July/016542.html and http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2012-July/016612.html for comments by Colin on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, Thomas Forster's 1998 paper

- Forster T. (1994) *Weak systems of set theory related to HOL*. In: Melham T.F., Camilleri J. (eds) Higher Order Logic Theorem Proving and Its Applications. HUG 1994. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol 859. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. doi:[10.1007/3-540-58450-1_43](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-58450-1_43)

is available on-line at various places including [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.48.2817&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

He says it is proved in

- Jensen RB, *On the consistency of a slight (?) modification of Quine's NF*, Synthese **19** 1969 pp 25--63, doi:[10.1007/978-94-010-1709-1_16](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-010-1709-1_16)
- Lake J, *Comparing Type theory and Set theory*, Zeitschrift fur Matematische Logik **21** 1975 pp  355-56. doi:[10.1002/malq.19750210144](https://doi.org/10.1002/malq.19750210144)

For a fanatically detailed proof and discussion see

- Mathias, A. R. D. *The strength of Mac Lane set theory*. Ann. Pure Appl. Logic **110** (2001), no. 1-3, 107–234,
  doi:[10.1016/S0168-0072(00)00031-2](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0168-0072%2800%2900031-2), [author pdf](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Eardm/maclane.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Colin, but I'm pretty confused.  None of Forster, Jensen or Mathias seem to mention finite order arithmetic (or $n$th order arithmetic) by name.  I haven't been able to get hold of Lake yet.  Forster says that Jensen and Lake prove the equivalence of ETCS (or rather, what he calls Mac Lane set theory) with something he calls TST.  But then, neither of the strings "TST" or "theory of simple types" appear in Jensen.  

Comment: So here's my understanding.  We know that ETCS is equivalent to bounded Zermelo with choice, also called Mac Lane set theory: there are plenty of references for that.  Forster says that Jensen and Lake prove that Mac Lane set theory is equivalent to something that Forster calls TST (Theory of Simple Types).  Jensen doesn't mention anything by this name, nor finite order arithmetic.  

Comment: Yes.  More than knowing ETCS has the strength of bounded Zermelo (which equals the strength of bounded Zermelo with choice) we have many published proofs.  I did not look at Jensen or Lake.  I could not get Jensen here at home.  And I always like to read Mathias.

ETCS is actually bi-interpretable with certain variants of bounded Z with choice, meaning they not only have the same strength but prove exactly the same theorems. The main issue there seems to be existence of transitive closures.

Comment: Ok, so I notice you (Colin) say "It has the proof theoretic strength of finite order arithmetic, in the sense of the simple theory of types with infinity (see Takeuti (1987, Part II))." (For others, Takeuti's book is reviewed in Zentralblatt here http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/scans.html?volume_=354&count_=020 (first edition) and here http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zbmath/search/?q=an%3A0609.03019 (second edition)). Where in Takeuti is it shown that TST is equivalent to finite-order arithmetic?

Comment: For Takeuti, "simple type theory" is synonymous with "higher (finite) order predicate logic," and does not include an axiom of infinity (though I think for most people simple type theory does include infinity).  this is my favorite reference on simple type theory.  So I call simple type theory with infinity "finite order arithmetic."

Comment: Ah, so it is not some union of higher analogues of $Z_2$...

Comment: For Takeuti, simple type theory is not that, as it does not have Peano axioms.  What I call finite order arithmetic is such a union

Comment: Ok, so I think I (and probably Tom too) would like to see a proof that TST+Infinity is the same (in the appropriate sense) as a Peano-style definition, or a $Z_2$-style definition, of finite-order arithmetic, rather than just calling TST+Infinity this. Because I can't see how they are the same, and the detail is how replacement/comprehension in the $Z_2$-style definition is handled in TST+Infninty.

Comment: The simple theory of types (including infinity, or plus infinity, depending on author) includes comprehension, and not replacement. This is also $Z_2$ in the references I use - notably Takeuti Proof Theory and Simpson Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic. I'm not sure what you mean by a Peano-style definition. What is a reference on it?

Comment: I meant something like a natural numbers object (possibly with some of the algebraic structure like +) and with some form of comprehension. I mentioned replacement because your systems ETR[n*] have it, and I was worried because ETCS doesn't have replacement. Sorry to keep nagging, but it's nice to pin these things down.

Comment: Yes it is nice.  This is subtle stuff and the published terminology is not at all as uniform as I would wish.  There is some category theory of middling-weak arithmetic, but much of it is constructive as it is intended for computer programming semantics, and I have not worked on it much. 